# ItemsControl: How to print WrapPanel on multiple Pages?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to print this, but only the first page appears.
for example if ItemsControlCodigos has 200 items, only 1 page appears.

How can this be done easily?

```
<FlowDocumentReader Name="FlowDocumentReader1" Margin="397,85,0,0">
        <FlowDocument Name="fd">
            <BlockUIContainer>
                <ItemsControl Name="ItemsControlCodigos" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"  />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="10pt" Text="{Binding Descricao, TargetNullValue='--'}" Width="100px" />
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="100px">
                                    <TextBlock FontFamily="IDAutomationHC39M" FontSize="10pt" Text="(" />
                                    <TextBlock FontFamily="IDAutomationHC39M" FontSize="10pt" Text="{Binding id_Produto}" />
                                    <TextBlock FontFamily="IDAutomationHC39M" FontSize="10pt" Text=")" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <Button Name="buttonExcluirItem" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Margin="-4,-1,-1,-1"

                                    Opacity="0.3"
                                    ToolTip="Excluir este Item">
                                    <Image Width="16" Height="16"  />
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>

            </BlockUIContainer>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentReader>
```

C#

```
private void ButtonImprimir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    // 20-05-2011
    PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();

    //pd.PrintVisual(ItemsControlCodigos, "Etiquetas");
    fd.PageHeight = pd.PrintableAreaHeight; 
    fd.PageWidth = pd.PrintableAreaWidth; 
    fd.PagePadding = new Thickness(50); 
    fd.ColumnGap = 0; 
    fd.ColumnWidth = pd.PrintableAreaWidth; 

    IDocumentPaginatorSource dps = fd;
    //dps.DocumentPaginator.PageCount;
    pd.PrintDocument(dps.DocumentPaginator, "flow doc"); 

}
```

Comment: This is something I am looking for too.

Comment: Me too. Maybe you found a solution in the meantime?

Comment: I guess you need to implement your own DocumentPaginator.

Comment: I think you have to set up your collection (= 200 items) to ItemsSource property of your ItemsControl. [Here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) is nice example how to do this:

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that the `DocumentPaginator` of `FlowDocument` does not paginate the `BlockUIContainer` i.e it does not break the `BlockUIContainer` content across multiple pages. I have answered the similar question here [Print flowdocument scroll viewer on multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544103/print-flowdocument-scroll-viewer-on-multiple-pages/18557631#18557631)

In short, you will have to create multiple BlockUIContainer each containing its itemsControl.

OR There is an unorthodox way of printing the whole Control(Visual) explained in this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339416/Printing-large-WPF-UserControls

where control was converted to Bitmap which was then chopped according to the pagesize to print.

Thanks

Comment: "In short, you will have to create multiple BlockUIContainer each containing its itemsControl". I presume you mean "item" instead of "itemscontrol"? If we have a list of dynamic size, does this become impossible via XAML? The only way I can envision doing it is by inserting the BlockUIContainers dynamically via code-behind.